# How to limit access to tests on Blackboard?

Tags: exams

I need to create tests on Blackboard and customize access time for different groups of students. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: So, you want different people to have different amounts of time on the same exam?  Or do you just want them to start at different times?

Comment: I need to cover both cases.

Comment: At a guess, to control the amount of time available to complete the test, probably create the same "test" as different tests, each with their own time limit. Controlling the time, and date, the test is accessible is probably able to be controlled by "class" or group. Depending on your variables, this could be a significant amount of permutations, or it could be a simple setup.

Comment: Blackboard calls this "adaptive release".

Comment: For each test Blackboard gives the possibility to add exceptions, and this works for me.